# preg_match - ignore optional parentheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following strings containing optional parentheses that are being matched with `preg_match`. The key is the input, and the value is the expected output:

```php
$strings = [
  '(prefix) (string in parens)'   => 'string in parens',
  '(prefix) string not in parens' => 'string not in parens',
  '(prefix) parens (at the end)'  => 'parens (at the end)',
];
```

Assuming I'd like to do this in a single `preg_match`, I currently have the following:

```php
preg_match('/^\(prefix\) (\((.+)\)|.+)$/', $input, $matches);
$output = (isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : $matches[1]);
```

This works, but requires a separate subpattern to detect which format was seen. Is there a better way to do this in a single subpattern? It's not enough to assume optional parentheses at either end of the subpattern, since there may be parentheses I'd like to include.

I know I have other options such as stripping prefix and parentheses separately, but I'd like to know if there's a better way to do this without altering the logic first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to get all the matching in a single capturing group is to use a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) to capture either after prefix from an opening till closing parenthesis, or a line without parenthesis but only optionally matching it at the end.

```
^\(prefix\)\h(?|\(([^()\n]+)\)|([^()\n]+(?:\([^()\n]+\))?))$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\(prefix\)\h` match `(prefix)` and a horizontal whitespace char
- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `\(([^()\n]+)\)` Match directly from `(` ... `)` and capture in group 1 what is in between
  - `|` Or
  - `(` Capture group 2

    - `[^()\n]+` Match any char except `(` `)` or a newline
    - `(?:\([^()\n]+\))?` Optionally match `(`...`)`
  - `)` Close group 2
- `)` Close branch reset group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/khHfTN/1)

Or as you pointed out, this pattern `^\(prefix\) (?|\((.+)\)|(.+))$` would be a broad match to capture either what is between the parenthesis, or all that follows.

Comment: Aha, looks like branch reset group is exactly what I was after. I'm aware my regex is very loose, but to avoid it looking like a huge leap to your answer, `^\(prefix\) (?|\((.+)\)|(.+))$` would be a good example.

Comment: @cmbuckley Yes you can also use that as a match, it depends on how specific you want the pattern to be. Using the `.+` is a very broad match indeed.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree - I was thinking more to show the smallest change possible, for anyone else who may read the question.